# Opencart seo url not working in information pages

Tags: url, seo, opencart

By following [this link](http://www.nixstudio.com/seo-friendly-url-opencart/) I enabled SEO URL in my opencart store. Every page is working fine except information pages. I'm still getting  that ugly URL

`http://example.com/?route=information/information&information_id=8`

instead of

```
http://example.com/privacy-policy
```

Did anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you entered the SEO keyword for information pages from `Catalog >> information >> Privacy Policy` in the admin panel?

other than that you can check in your database (using phpmyadmin ) in `url_alias` table see if there is some row like `some_number | information_id=8 | privacy-policy`